# What is the better ASP.NET MVC 3.0 Custom Validation approach

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking into ASP.NET MVC 3.0 custom validation and found some articles about that:

**First**: http://tdryan.blogspot.com/2010/12/aspnet-mvc-3-custom-validation.html

**Second**: http://thepursuitofalife.com/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-javascript-validation-with-custom-validators/

**Third**: http://samipoimala.com/it/2010/11/29/unobtrusive-client-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3/

But each of articles describing a bit different approaches...

In the **First** article they creating `CustomValidatonAtribute` and `CustomValidaor` Inherited form `DataAnnotationsModelValidator<CustomValidatonAtribute>`, than they register all that in `Global.asx`, without any jQuery custom validaton methods.

In **Second** article they created just `ValidatonAttribute` witch implemented `IClientValidatable` then they crating custom jQueryValidator method on client side.

In the **Third** article they crating `ModelClientValidator` inherited from `ModelClientValidationRule` plus jQuery custom validator method on client side.

It is a bit confusing which approach to pick, but i think o would go with **Third** one first it is looking for me more lightweight that other ones.

I know that i may need to try each of them to see how it is looking on practice and looks like it is depends what validation is required.

Should i inherit my custom validator from `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` of from `ModelClientValidationRule`?

But may be some have any opinions on that?

Answer (score 0):

for my also was confuse. But I finally use the `System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute`  for validation on the client. And for the server I make a  validator class that inherit from ValidationAttribute and I override the method `protected override ValidationResult IsValid` . For my was the easiest option.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i think remote validation is nice to have when you need to check something in data base (e.g: User Name or Email is already exists, etc) otherwise i would use real client unobtrusive validation.

Comment: True... I use it in that case.